# Plotly works in R Script, but does not work when using source in RMarkdown

Tags: r, plotly, flexdashboard, facet-wrap

I am working on a dashboard. I wrote a script to break up my rmarkdown file (flexdashboard). When I run the script in R it works fine. However when I use source, and try to render the document. I get the error "At least one layer must contain all faceting variables, Name").

I have done this before with similar types of data. I was expecting the dashboard to load.

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(19368, 19368, 19368, 19368, 
19368, 19368, 19368, 19368, 19369, 19369, 19369, 19369, 19369, 
19369, 19369, 19366, 19366, 19366, 19366, 19366, 19366, 19366, 
19366), class = "Date"), Name = c("Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", 
"Player 5", "Player 7", "Player 10", "Player 11", "Player 12", 
"Player 11", "Player 7", "Player 10", "Player 3", "Player 2", 
"Player 1", "Player 12", "Player 10", "Player 12", "Player 3", 
"Player 5", "Player 7", "Player 2", "Player 1", "Player 11"), 
RPE = c(6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 
4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4), Legginess = c(7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 5, 8, 5, 
8, 5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4), Breathlessness = c(5, 
5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 6, 6, 3, 4, 6, 3, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 4, 
6, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

rpe_plot <- rpe %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, RPE)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  labs(title = "RPE for the Week",
   x = "", 
   y = "") +
  facet_wrap(~Name, scales = "free")

plot_1 <- ggplotly(rpe_plot)
```

I then load this on my rmarkdown document using source.

```
---
title: "RPE_Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: fill
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---
```

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(plotly)
library(here)
library(data.table)
```

```
# RPE Summary {data-orientation=rows}

## Row

### Individual RPE
```

```
source(here("RPE_Dashboard/RPE_Script.R"))

plot_1
```

Comment: So what exactly does the markdown document look like? Is this exactly what appears in a code chunk in the document? If this part works for you, how do we create the version that doesn't work so we can debug the issue?

Comment: ---
title: "RPE_Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: fill
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(plotly)
library(here)
library(data.table)
```

# RPE Summary {data-orientation=rows}

## Row

### Individual RPE
```{r}
source(here("RPE_Dashboard/RPE_Script.R"))

plot_1
```

Comment: Sorry that was poor on my part for not including the rmarkdown

Comment: So where are you loading your data in the markdown version? I would be better to edit your question with the markdown code so it can be properly formatted

Comment: Everything works with read.csv.